# typescript mocha describe is not a function

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, describe

The issue I have is that mocha-typescript keeps throwing an error that `describe` is not defined.

```
    TypeError: mocha_typescript_1.describe is not a function
    at DatabaseTest.WrongPath (test/database_test.ts:21:9)
    at Context.<anonymous> (node_modules/mocha-typescript/index.ts:218:22)
```

My tsconfig.json

```
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "typeRoots": [
          "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "types": [
          "node", "mocha", "chai"
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/**/*.ts",
        "test/**/*.ts"
      ],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
      ]
    }
```

My package.json

```
    {
      //omitted
      "main": "App.js",
      "scripts": {
        "pretest": "tsc",
        "test": "nyc mocha --require ts-node/register test/**/*_test.ts ",
        "watch": "mocha-typescript-watch",
        "prepare": "tsc"
      },

      // ommitted

      "dependencies": {
        "@types/chai": "^4.0.6",
        "@types/jsesc": "^0.4.29",
        "@types/mocha": "^2.2.44",
        "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
        "@types/sqlite3": "^3.1.1",
        "chai": "^4.1.2",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "express-longpoll": "0.0.4",
        "jsesc": "^2.5.1",
        "mocha": "^4.0.1",
        "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.12",
        "nyc": "^11.3.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
        "sequelize": "^4.26.0",
        "sequelize-typescript": "^0.6.1",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.0",
        "sqlite3": "^3.1.13",
        "ts-events": "^3.2.0",
        "ts-node": "^3.3.0",
        "typescript": "^2.6.2",
        "typings": "^2.1.1"
      }
    }
```

`database_test.ts`:

```
    //Unit testing script for Database.ts
    /// <reference path="../node_modules/mocha-typescript/globals.d.ts" />
    //// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts" />

    import { suite, test, describe, slow, timeout  } from "mocha-typescript"
    import { assert } from "chai";
    import 'mocha'

    @suite(slow(1000), timeout(3000))
    export class SampleTest {

        @test testFunc(){
            describe("Sample function", ()=>{
                it("Should succeed without any problems", (done) => {
                    assert.isTrue(true);
                    done();
                })
            });
        }
    }
```

Full log:

```
    > project@1.0.0 pretest /home/user/folder/project
    > tsc


    > project@1.0.0 test /home/user/folder/project
    > nyc mocha --require ts-node/register test/**/*.ts



      SampleTest
        1) testFunc            

      0 passing (13ms)
      1 failing

      1) SampleTest
           testFunc:
         TypeError: mocha_typescript_1.describe is not a function
          at DatabaseTest.WrongPath (test/database_test.ts:21:9)
          at Context.<anonymous> (node_modules/mocha-typescript/index.ts:218:22)


    ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
    File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines |Uncovered Lines |
    ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
    All files |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |  Unknown |                |
    ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|
    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

As you can see I've tried multiple things such as settings `typeRoots` and `types` in `tsconfig.json`, `import mocha` and two different type definiton files. None of them worked and I'm tangled up in all the possible combinations.

I've been trying to get typescript-mocha running for a while now and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. A clear explanation I don't have, but I'd certainly like one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the error is given because of a double keyword declaration.
Apparently `import 'mocha'` is enough to declare the `describe` keyword.

I simply had to adjust the import line from

```
import { suite, test, describe, slow, timeout  } from "mocha-typescript"
```

to

```
import { suite, test, slow, timeout  } from "mocha-typescript"
```

Comment: I was able to resolve `describe` and `it` by just using `import 'mocha'`. Thank you!