# Describe is not defined exception on Typescript, Mocha and VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, mocha.js

For some reason my mocha test scripts are throwing an exception of "describe is not defined".

I have read and tried the solutions suggested by these SO questions but no luck:
[describe is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46193653/referenceerror-describe-is-not-defined)
["Mocha describe is not defined duplicate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18430135/mocha-describe-is-not-defined)

other links are:
[typescript mocha describe is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716547/typescript-mocha-describe-is-not-a-function)

This is my VSCode launch.json.

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Mocha Tests",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
  "args": [
    "-u",
    "tdd",
    "--timeout",
    "999999",
    "--colors",
    "${workspaceRoot}/dist/tests/**/*.js"
  ],
  "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/tests/**/*.js"],
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
}
```

This is my mocha test script:

```
import "mocha";
import assert = require("assert");

describe("Init", () => {
  before(() => {
    console.log("before-hook");
  });

  it("connected", () => {
    assert(true, "is not true");
  });
});
```

And this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [ "es6" ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? I really need to get back to using mocha.

Comment: Found the culprit - it was mocha. Downgraded to version 5.2.0 from 6+ and it was working again. However this is just a workaround and I need to find out what really was the issue.

Comment: When migrating a JS project to TypeScript, I got this error. It went away when I renamed the test file from `.jsx` to `.tsx`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

I have figured out the issue after installing Mocha 6.1.1.

On the launch.json, change the args array from "tdd" to "bdd" so that:
`"-u", "bdd"`

Version 5.x worked with the "tdd" option so the next major version caused this hiccup of a badly written configuration.

Comment: Nope, you just forgot it.

Comment: and actually, in our case style was bdd, that is why tdd option is not working.

Comment: thank you for coming back to answer your question. Saved me tons of time.

Answer (score 3):

Removing this import:

```
import { describe, it } from 'mocha';
```

Seems to fix it for me.

Comment: This appears to fix my issue. Any reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps it may works by specifying `mocha` in `types` inside `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": [
      "node",
      "mocha" <--- specify here
    ]
  },
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Also don't forget to install `@types/mocha`

```
npm install @types/mocha --save-dev
```

Hope it can solve your issue

Comment: Added mocha to the types array in tsconfig.json and packages.json, still getting:  
    TypeError: mocha_1.describe is not a function

Comment: Please see my comment on the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Are your test files written in Javascript (you refer to *.js in your launch.json)?

I'm using ts-node to debug the unit tests, and refer directly to the Typescript test files, so my launch.json entry looks like below. Before I used ts-node, I got the 'describe is not defined' error when running from inside VS Code.

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Unit tests (mocha)",
  "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha",
  "args": [
    "-r",
    "ts-node/register",
    "--timeout",
    "999999",
    "--colors",
    "${workspaceFolder}/test/**/*Test.ts",
  ],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "protocol": "inspector"
}
```

Comment: Test files are written in Typescript.

Comment: Dan, please see my comment on the question above.

Comment: When migrating a JS project to TypeScript, I got this error. It went away when I renamed the test file from `.jsx` to `.tsx`